# How do I configure Rollup for a React Component Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollupjs

I'm trying to configure Rollup for a React component library (using v3), and am having a real fight. I don't know exactly what I'm doing, but chasing each error just leads to another error. I'm confident that this should be pretty straight forward and is a common use case so I'm hoping someone might be able to help?

Originally I started just with:

```
const peerDepsExternal = require("rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external");
const resolve = require("@rollup/plugin-node-resolve");
const commonjs = require("@rollup/plugin-commonjs");
const postcss = require("rollup-plugin-postcss");

module.exports = {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: {
    dir: "build",
    format: "esm",
    preserveModules: true,
    preserveModulesRoot: "src",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  // external: [/@babel\/runtime/],
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    postcss(),
    peerDepsExternal(),
  ],
};
```

But I hit an error where it was unable to find any JSX files:

> Could not resolve "./withSVG" from "src/hoc/index.js"

So I added in the babel JSX plugin:

```
const jsx = require("rollup-plugin-jsx");
...
plugins: [
    resolve(),
    jsx({ factory: "React.createElement" }),
    commonjs(),
    postcss(),
    peerDepsExternal(),
]
```

This then led to another error, where it was unable to parse the chainable operator `.?`:

> [!] (plugin commonjs--resolver) Error: Parse Error: Line 20: Unexpected token .
> src/utils/linkStores.js
> Error: Parse Error: Line 20: Unexpected token .

So I assumed I needed to insert babel into here somewhere:

```
const { babel } = require("@rollup/plugin-babel");
...
plugins: [
    resolve(),
    jsx({ factory: "React.createElement" }),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    }),
    postcss(),
    peerDepsExternal(),
]
```

This gave the following message:

> babelHelpers: 'bundled' option was used by default. It is recommended to configure this option explicitly, read more here: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel#babelhelpers

Following the link gives the follow blurb:

> 'runtime' - you should use this especially when building libraries with Rollup. It has to be used in combination with @babel/plugin-transform-runtime and you should also specify @babel/runtime as dependency of your package. Don't forget to tell Rollup to treat the helpers imported from within the @babel/runtime module as external dependencies when bundling for cjs & es formats. This can be accomplished via regex (external: [/@babel/runtime/]) or a function (external: id => id.includes('@babel/runtime')). It's important to not only specify external: ['@babel/runtime'] since the helpers are imported from nested paths (e.g @babel/runtime/helpers/get) and Rollup will only exclude modules that match strings exactly.

So as I'm trying to create a component library I added:

```
const babelPluginTransformRuntime = require("@babel/plugin-transform-runtime");
...
plugins: [
    babelPluginTransformRuntime,
    resolve(),
    jsx({ factory: "React.createElement" }),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      babelHelpers: "runtime",
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    }),
    postcss(),
    peerDepsExternal(),
]
```

With a `babel.config.js` of:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    plugins: [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
            {
                runtime: "automatic",
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

But now I get the following error and I can't seem to find any way to resolve this one:

> [!] (plugin commonjs--resolver) RollupError: You have declared using "runtime" babelHelpers, but transforming /home/ian/src/chart-it/packages/react/src/index.js resulted in "inline". Please check your configuration.

Can anyone suggest a working rollup config for a react component library (not TypeScript)?

Here's a link to the repository if anyone wants to test an answer: https://github.com/IPWright83/chart-it/tree/fixingPackage

Comment: Here is 1 configuration that is working for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-u6hhmc If you don't need typescript, remove the typescript things from rollup config and package.json.

Comment: @vighnesh153 I get invalid tokens when it comes across the first react `<` when using that setup

Comment: I just opened the link in incognito window and ran `npm run build` in the terminal and it succeeds. Is the link not working for you or is it not working in your package?

Comment: @vighnesh153 I meant it doesn't work for my setup

Comment: @vighnesh153 that's also for an app, but I think a library needs different config.

Comment: @vighnesh153 here is an example of my setup https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-upefmh?file=src/components/test.js I've noticed that `?.` is fine in a JSX file but fails in a regular JS file.

Comment: I added a `.babelrc` file in the project and commented out: `jsx({ factory: 'React.createElement' })` from rollup config plugins: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ojxn48